# Получение IP-адреса входящего соединения RESTful

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Использую для создания REST-сервиса jersey+grizzly.
Нужно получить IP адрес клиента, отправившего запрос.
Пробовал с помощью HttpServletRequest

```
@GET
@Path("test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getIp(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    String ip = "0.0.0.0";
    try {
        ip = req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For").split(",")[0];
    } catch (Exception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(MyResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ip;
```

Но выпадает ошибка

> SEVERE: null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.xomka.horsemacloudserver.MyResource.registration(MyResource.java:
>   55)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHa
>   ndlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethod
>   Dispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethod
>   Dispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatch
>   erProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:2
>   05)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethod
>   Dispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(Resour
>   ceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Resourc
>   eMethodInvoker.java:347)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(Resourc
>   eMethodInvoker.java:102)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:32
>   6)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(Request
>   Scope.java:317)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:
>   305)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHand
>   ler.java:1154)
>           at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service
>   (GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:
>   224)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(Abs
>   tractThreadPool.java:591)
>           at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(Abstra
>   ctThreadPool.java:571)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Каким образом можно получить IP адрес?

Comment: А request.getRemoteAddr() что возвращает?

Comment: То же самое возвращает

Comment: Что находится в этой строке com.xomka.horsemacloudserver.MyResource.registration(MyResource.java: 55) ?

Comment: @GenCloud ,         ip = req.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For").split(",")[0];